# Using a function of a struct results in segfault

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, function-pointers

I have a struct with two pointers to functions and some data. The functions are definition-wise the same, however they should perform different tasks (which is why they have different names in the original source). If I use the first function, all goes well, but if I use the second functions, I get a segfault - even if I pass the same pointer to both functions.

The pointers are neither NULL nor garbage, or else both would fail - but somehow only the latter gets segfaulted. Why is that?

I have the following code:

```
typedef void (*funcOneDef)(void*);
typedef void (*funcTwoDef)(void*);
typedef struct structImpl* structPt;

struct structImpl {
    void *data;
    funcOneDef funcOne;
    funcTwoDef funcTwo;
}; 

structPt create(void *data, funcOneDef funcOne, funcTwoDef funcTwo)
{
    structPt test = malloc(sizeof(test));
    test->data = data;
    test->funcOne = funcOne;
    test->funcTwo = funcTwo;
    return test;
}

void execFuncOne(structPt test) 
{
    test->funcOne(test->data); //works!
}

void execFuncTwo(structPt test)
{
    test->funcTwo(test->data); //segfault!
}
```

PS: No need to test this, because somehow this works, but my original source - which is basically the same - doesn't?

Comment: I'd suggest you "Easter egg" between this version and the one that fails.

Comment: Compile with debugging info and all warnings, and learn to use a debugger. On Linux, compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and debug with `gdb`.

Comment: `test = malloc(sizeof(test))` is wrong; should be `test = malloc(sizeof *test)`.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks, this works! I suspected some memory problem but somehow didn't test for it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't the line `structPt test = malloc(sizeof(test));` be `structPt test = malloc(sizeof(structImpl));`?

Comment: malloc(sizeof(structImpl)) throws an error, it should be: malloc(sizeof(struct structImpl)); or malloc(sizeof *test); but yeah, thanks!